# Remove class function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/Todorovic/pen/PGLPAP?editors=0010  `icon($sky); in ajax call`

Everything works as expected, but displaying weather icons is not wokring.
I dont understand what is wrong here? Why it doesnt work? I asume it has something with ajax synchronous request but if someone could explain how to fix this...

---

Comment: Please define "_is not working_". And also add the relevant code to the post, external-only snippets are worth of nothing.

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem.

Comment: Your  Code seems to only have that issue at codepen.io but at jsfiddle, everything seems to be working fine. you may check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=unU57xiieG

Answer (score 1):

```
function addIcon(value) {
  console.log(value);
  ('div.' + value).removeClass('hide');
}
```

Forgot your Jquery $ -- Technically speaking the removeClass function doesn't exist on what's in the parens.

`$('div.' + value).removeClass('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $ for jQuery

Change:

```
('div.' + value).removeClass('hide');
```

To:

```
$('div.' + value).removeClass('hide');
```